# When I pause my timer, then try to start it again, it does not run

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm building an app in Swift 3. When I press start the first time my timer begins, but when I pause it and try to press start again, the timer does not budge. To give context, the timer, with an amount of time attached to it, is selected from a table. each time the timer load, the start button works initially.

```
protocol TimerViewControllerDelegate: class {
func viewController(_ controller: ViewController, didFinishEditing item: TaskData)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var timerTaskName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timerTimeSetting: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

weak var delegate: TimerViewControllerDelegate?

var timerTask: TaskData?
var timer: Timer?
var progressViewSpeed: Double = 0.0

@IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
    timer?.invalidate()
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    delegate?.viewController(self, didFinishEditing: timerTask!)
}

@IBAction func startButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    timerTask?.startTime = Date()
    runTimer()
    if timerTask?.isTaskRunning == true {
        runTimer()
        self.startButton.isEnabled = false
        self.pauseButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        //retrieve start time and run
        timerTask?.startTime = Date()
        runTimer()
        self.startButton.isEnabled = false
        self.pauseButton.isEnabled = true
    }
}

func runTimer() {
    guard timer == nil else {
        return
    }

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func pauseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if timerTask?.isTaskRunning == true {
        timer?.invalidate()
        if let timerTask = timerTask, timerTask.isTaskRunning {

            // Calculate the difference between now and when the timerTask was started
            let difference = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(timerTask.startTime!))
            timerTask.taskRemaining -= difference
            if timerTask.taskRemaining == 0 {
                // Do something when there's no time remaining on the task?
            }

            timerTask.startTime = nil
        }
    }

    else {

        timerTask?.startTime = Date()
        runTimer()
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
    }

    self.startButton.isEnabled = true
    self.pauseButton.isEnabled = false
}

/*
@IBAction func resetButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    timer.invalidate()
    seconds = 60
    self.timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
    if self.resumeTapped == true {
        self.resumeTapped = false
        self.pauseButton.setTitle("Pause",for: .normal)
    }
    isTimerRunning = false
    pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    startButton.isEnabled = true
}
*/

func updateTimer() {
    guard let timerTask = timerTask else {
        return
    }

    if timerTask.taskRemaining < 1 {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        //Send alert to indicate "time's up!"
    } else {
        updateTime()
    }
    progressViewSpeed = 1 / Double(timerTask.taskRemaining)
    progressView.progress += Float(progressViewSpeed)
}

func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
    let hours = Int(time) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(time) % 60
    return String(format:"%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let timerTask = timerTask else {
        return
    }

    if timerTask.isTaskRunning {
        startButton.isEnabled = false
        pauseButton.isEnabled = true
        runTimer()
    } else {
        startButton.isEnabled = true
        pauseButton.isEnabled = false
    }

    timerTaskName.text = timerTask.task
    updateTime()

    self.progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2).scaledBy(x: 1, y: 150)

}

func updateTime() {
    guard let timerTask = timerTask else {
        return
    }

    if let startTime = timerTask.startTime {
        // Calculate the difference between now and when the timerTask was started
        let difference = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime))

        if timerTask.taskRemaining == difference {
            // Do something when there's no time remaining on the task
            timer?.invalidate()
            timer = nil
        }

        timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(timerTask.taskRemaining - difference))
    } else {
        timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(timerTask.taskRemaining))
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger and step through the code. See where things go wrong.

Comment: You mean with a breakpoint? Where do you think the best place would be to put one to help me solve this problem?

Comment: Since your issue is after pressing the Start button. Put a breakpoint in your `startButton` method to begin with. You'll probably end up putting one in your `pauseButtonTapped` method too. Keep trying and narrow down what the issue is and then figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to invalidate it and recreate it. "isPaused" bool to keep track of the state

```
var isPaused = true
var timer: Timer?    
@IBAction func pauseResume(sender: AnyObject) {     
    if isPaused{
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(ViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        pauseButton.isHidden = false
        startButton.isHidden = true
        isPaused = false
    } else {

        pauseButton.isHidden = true
        startButton.isHidden = false
        timer.invalidate()
        isPaused = true
    }
    }
```

Comment: My pause button doesn't turn into a resume button. When I press pause it enables a start button and vice-versa. When I go from the timer back to the tableview and then back to the timer again, the button works from where the timer left off.

Comment: I'm confused because I thought that I was recreating with my startButtonTapped function

Comment: To be more specific, the else portion is when I try to do that, because it follows the case where the timer is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've invalidated an NSTimer, you can't use it again. You should create the new object.

See here for more [From NSTimer Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTimer)

Calling this method requests the removal of the timer from the current run loop; as a result, you should always call the invalidate method from the same thread on which the timer was installed. Invalidating the timer immediately disables it so that it no longer affects the run loop. The run loop then removes and releases the timer, either just before the invalidate method returns or at some later point. Once invalidated, timer objects cannot be reused.

Comment: I'm just confused because I thought that I was addressing this with my else statement in startButtonTapped

Comment: if I pause, go from the timer back to the table view, then return to the timer and hit start, it starts just fine.

Comment: Try setting the timer to nil in 'pauseButtonTapped' method after invalidating it.